# Tableau: Parameter with URL Action

Tags: url, drop-down-menu, parameters, tableau-api

My goal is to create a drop down in Tableau and clicking on any option on the drop down would open a window based on the URL associated with the drop down option.

Is this achievable in Tableau?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do exactly what you ask for in Tableau!

But you can achieve something close to it.

1. Create a Calculated field `[one]` with the formula `1`. You might want to use any measure of your data set in case that works for you
2. Create a Parameter `[Link Select]` as a string list, give it a "value" and a "display as" name that identify your links
3. Create a calculated field `[link]`: `CASE [Link Select] WHEN 'link1' THEN 'www.abc.com' WHEN 'link2' THEN 'www.def.com' END`
4. Create a visualisation that you like (eg. use your `[one]` to create a circular button and give it a suitabale label, eg. 'Click Me') then drag `[link]` to the details pane
5. go to worksheet/actions or dashboard/actions and add an URL action, for the URL choose the `[link]` field and change the settings to suit your needs
6. Now, you can choose a link from your parameter and click on your graph to go to the specified URL.

In the end you just need one click more after you choose from your parameter to go to the URL. Which in my opinion is better UI design anyway, because usually using a drop down, does not open a new link.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense and seems to be the best possible solution! Please take my bounty! :)